# Identity theft issue: Fidelity showing another person’s profile on my 401k, Fidelity closed the request

Tags: united-states, 401k, online-banking, identity-theft, fidelity

My employer provides 401k and I opened a 401k with Fidelity in September. I have been contributing to the 401k since. Recently, I logged into my account and my user profile on Fidelity is showing a totally different name, address, phone number, and email for the same username and password. When I opened it back in September it was showing showing correct information.

I contacted fidelity immediately and they said that they would fix it. Since they didn't do anything ( they didn't get back to me), I also tried name change request on their website but they replied saying they denied the request (since name change requires, court order, marriage license or other documents)

What should I do here? I have substantial fund & I am afraid that I will lose the money.

For reference

- Yes my contribution is showing up correctly
- Yes it’s being invested correctly
- I haven’t been able to check if ssn is correct. Any idea where to click on to check?

Comment: I strongly suggest you ask your HR department to lean on Fidelity to fix it, and also contact Fidelity again yourself. Also suggest you change the password to that account, and any other account that shares the same password [which is not a good thing to do, for reasons such as this].

Comment: For 401ks, from my experience, the data comes from your company's HR. It may not have been Fidelity who screwed up.

Comment: Did Fidelity ask you to change your password (and username) immediately after you reported this issue to them ?  Or did they say that this is just an error on their computer system and that your account is still safe with them ? What is their official explanation for this strange event that happens to your account ?

Comment: How long is "_Since they didn't do anything (they didn't get back to me)_"? Are you talking hours, days, weeks?